# Помогите с gtest

Tags: c++, cmake, тестирование, clion, gtest

Я пытаюсь научиться пользоваться gtest. Использую Ide clion, настраиваю по этому туторталу

> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/creating-google-test-run-debug-configuration-for-test.html#gtest-config

Я создал простенький проект, где есть 1 заголовочный файл summator.h, содержащий объявление функций сложения и вычитаний, соответственно в summator.cpp я написал реализацию данных функций. В проекте создал пустую папку Gtest_tests в ней создал поддиректорию lib и перенес туда содержимое репозитория gtest.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал внутри папки gtest cmake файл и напсиал туда

```
# 'Google_test' is the subproject name
project(Google_tests)

# 'lib' is the folder with Google Test sources
add_subdirectory(lib)
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})

# 'Google_Tests_run' is the target name
# 'test1.cpp tests2.cpp' are source files with tests
add_executable(Google_Tests_run summ_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Google_Tests_run gtest gtest_main)
```

В основном cmake проекта написал

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(summator)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc")
add_subdirectory(Google_tests)
file(GLOB sources
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/*.h"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
add_executable(summator ${sources})
```

Далее я написал файл с самими тестами summ_test.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "summator.h"

TEST(SummTest, test1){
    ASSERT_EQ(10, summ(5, 5));
}

TEST(SummTest, test2){
    ASSERT_EQ(-5, sub(5, 10));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

При запуска данного файла я получаю следующую картину
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне исправить данные ошибки, почему ссылки на функции не определены ??

Comment: ну вы же уже опытный участник - почему вы приводите ошибке скрином? Вы же должны знать, что это не удобно

Comment: ну а по поводу ошибки - налицо то, что вы не указали где искать инклюд `summator.h`